# Dialog Box with a comment

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I am using JQuery Dialog box to alert users that they are about to delete an item. I need to place a comments text box inside the dialog, and then use this comment to update the record in the database.

I have the following JQuery function:

```
$('.releaseMessage').click(function (evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    var msgId = $(this).closest('tr').children().eq(2).html();
    var senderBIC = $(this).closest('tr').children().eq(3).html();

    var idPredefineDetail = $(this).closest("div").find("input[name=idPredefineDetail]").value();



    var _msgId = JSON.stringify({ msgId: msgId, senderBIC: senderBIC });
    $("#release-dialog-text").text("You are about to release message ("+ msgId + ")");
    $("#release-dialog").dialog({
        model: true,
        buttons: {
            Ok: function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "Default.aspx/ReleaseMessage",
                    data: _msgId,
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function () {
                    },
                    error: function (xml, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        alert(xml.status + "||" + xml.responseText);
                    }

                });

            },
            Cancel: function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }
    });
});
```

And my DIV for the dialog is:

```
<div id="release-dialog" title="Release Message">

    <div id="release-dialog-text">

    </div>
    <input id="comment" type="text" />
</div>
```

Comment: so what's the issue ?

Comment: And what is the question or problem you are having?

Comment: As the post states, i need to assign to a local variable the comment that is being written in the text box. I've tried 

var strComment = $('release-dialog input').val(); 

and

var strComment = $('#comment').val()

both return no text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok sorted this using this method:

window.parent.$('#release-dialog')
               .attr('title', 'Release Message')
               .html('Enter your comment')
               .dialog({

```
                     ... rest of dialog stuff 
           var comment = window.parent.$('#releasecomment').val();
```